# Fuzzystrmatch Postgresql similarity func with array

Tags: postgresql

How do I pass an array to the `SIMILARITY ()`function

I am looking for something similar to the following:

```
SELECT denomination, is_active 
   FROM MyTable WHERE 
SIMILARITY(denomination, ['Coke', 'Coque']) > 0.4;
```

Comment: What semantics are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANY, but then you have to use the operator form, not the functional form.  pg_trgm is a bit weird, in that the operator and the function are framed in opposite ways, one is distance and one is similarity.

```
set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold=0.6;  -- That is, 1 - 0.4

SELECT denomination, is_active 
   FROM MyTable WHERE 
   denomination % ANY (ARRAY['Coke', 'Coque']);
```

Comment: It's works thanks

Answer (score 1):

The similarity function does not take in array as argument so it will not do what you want out of the box

You have a couple of options create a wrapper function that takes in array that the calls Similarity and returns a value to compare against.

2nd option is do a cross join to the array like so

```
SELECT denomination, is_active , unnest  
    FROM mytable  cross join ( 
        select * from 
        unnest(array['coke', 'coqe'])
    ) dd
    where SIMILARITY(denomination, unnest) > 0.4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a DB expert nor good at SQL but here is my solution.

I basically use a function called **unnest()**. Thus, I can iterate over the array and check the similarity value for each item then compare it to **similarity** input, which is a *float*.

The accepted answer uses `set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold=0.6;` which is a global setting as far as I know.

Also, if you create a function to do the job and the function is not `VOLATILE` but is `STABLE`, you **cannot use** `set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`. (At least that was what happened to me).

**Caution:** I didn't compare my approach to **(ANY)** approach in terms of performance. Also, @zsheep already offered a similar solution that uses the `unnest()` function in it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function_name (input text, similarity float) RETURNS
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT
       FROM unnest(ARRAY['item','anotherItem', 'third-ish']) element
       WHERE SIMILARITY (input, element) > similarity
   );
$ function $
```